# How to add specific values together in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
d = {1:2, 2:4, 3:6, 4:8, 5:10}
```

Is there a way to add together multiple values? For example I want to add together every value from 1-3 that should give me 12.

Comment: Remember (most) dictionaries aren't ordered, so there isn't a straightforward way to do what you want.  (That doesn't mean it is impossible though!) If your dictionary truly looks like that, it shouldn't be too hard, in fact, but the general case is trickier.

Comment: Will the range of keys you want to add always be consecutive? (i.e. not 1,2,5)

Comment: yes they are consecutive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something like:

```
>>> d = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10}
>>> start = 1
>>> end = 3
>>> sum(d[i] for i in range(start, end + 1) if i in d)
12
```

This will sum the values from `d` for the keys 1-3 (inclusive).

Comment: You can use `sum(d[i] if i in d else 0 for i in range(start, end + 1))` to avoid a `KeyError` if `i` is not in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {1:2, 2:4, 3:6, 4:8, 5:10}

total = 0
for n in range(1, 3+1):
    if n in d:
        total += d[n]
print(total)
```